# Can't execute shell script in AUR PKGBUILD

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, aur, pkgbuild

In the PKGBUILD file for an AUR I am working on, I get the following error in my package() function:

```
./install.sh: No such file or directory
```

here is the function:

```
package() {
    cd /opt/"$pkgname"/pymoab
    ./install.sh
    python setup.py install
}
```

The file is in the directory, and it is called 'install.sh.cmake'.

I have tried changing the command in the package() function multiple ways, including:

```
bash install.sh
bash install.sh.cmake
bash ./install.sh
bash ./install.sh.cmake
./install.sh
./install.sh.cmake
. ./install.sh
. ./install.sh.cmake
```

All give the same error.

I originally wrote this as a set of shells scripts, which work well. In the shell script the command is:

```
bash install.sh
```

So I'm not sure why it doesn't work in the package() function.

I am testing this on a fresh arch distro (junest: https://github.com/fsquillace/junest)

All input appreciated. Let me know if I can provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was missing a compile flag on the initial cmake call, namely: `DENABLE_PYMOAB`

Comment: While correct in your particular case, this answer does not explain why the target directory already exists while the package is currently being created.

Comment: i think in this case it was created in the `build()` function so it existed for `package()` to see

Answer (score 1):

You're cd-ing to `/opt` in `package()`

There is definitely no `./install` in `/opt` as it is not `$srcdir` or `$pkgdir`

Maybe you mean `$srcdir/opt/$pkgname/pymoab` or `$pkgdir/opt/$pkgname/pymoab`?

Comment: perhaps, but the main issue was a missing compile flag actually that generated the actual `.sh` script